# Are destructed (modified) objects always the receiver when traced back to the most primitive method?

Tags: ruby, oop, immutability

Some methods are destructive on the receiver. For example, given an array `a` and an object`b`, applying the method `Array#push` as `a.push(b)` modifies `a`, but not `b`. We can wrap this in another method:

```
class Object
  def into a
    a.push(self)
  end
end
b.into(a)
```

so that this time, not the receiver `b` but the argument `a` is modified. Nevertheless, `Object#into` internally calls `Array#push`, so that when we trace the internal process (within Ruby implementation), we can say that, ultimately, the modified object `a` is the receiver in this case as well.

Are all cases of destruction (modification) ultimately traceable to a method where the modifee is the receiver?

If so, what is making it so? Is it for the sake of C-implementation, or does it follow from object orientation, or is it just coincidence?

Comment: Naturally, _something_ is going to be the receiver of a destructive operation, right? I'd say, it's OO. And in the C code it probably looks like `rb_push(ary1, ary2)` (no objects, no receivers, just function)

Comment: [`Module#append_features`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-append_features) modifies the argument while leaving the receiver unchanged

Comment: @Stefan Great. That is indeed an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't necessarily that way, but it is conventionally that way. The reason is that each object is meant to be responsible for handling its own state. Having a message to an object leave that object the same but modify another object generally goes against that principle.

This is an old OO idea. You don't modify objects — instead, you ask them to modify themselves.